# how to do Python unittest for while loop?

Tags: python, python-unittest

When I write a unit test case, I don't know how to design the test case for a while loop. Could someone give me a guide to writing a unit testcase for the below while-loop code snippet? Many thanks.

```python
def judge(arg):
    flag = 1 if arg > 15 else 0
    
    return flag

def while_example(a,b):
    output = "NOK"
    while True:
        ret1 = judge(a)
        ret2 = judge(b)

        if ret1 == 0 and ret2 == 0:
            print "both a and b are OK"
            output = "OK"
            break
        else:
            print "both a and b are not OK"
            a =- 1
            b =- 1
     return output
```

Comment: Why does the function "judge" always return the same thing regardless of inputs? One problem I see here is that there is no output behavior that you could capture (eg "return result"); the only behavior that occurs external to this function is a print statement.

Comment: thanks.the while loop is a endless loop if both ret1 and ret2 do not equal 0. so there is no special output.  I have corrected the function "judge" problem and added output statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have overcome this unit test issue, below is my answer

```html
import unittest
import sys 

from StringIO import * 
from while_loop import *
from mock import * 



class TestJudge(unittest.TestCase):
    def testJudge_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(judge(16), 1)
        
    def testJudge_2(self):
        self.assertEqual(judge(15), 0)

class TestWhile(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_while_1(self):
        judge = Mock(side_effect=[0,0])
        out = StringIO()
        sys.stdout = out 
        a = while_example(1, 1)
        output = out.getvalue().strip()
        self.assertEqual(output, "both a and b are OK")
    
    def test_while_2(self):
        judge = Mock(side_effect=[1,0])
        out = StringIO()
        sys.stdout = out 
        a = while_example(18, 12)
        output = out.getvalue().strip()
        self.assertEqual(output, 'both a and b are not OK\nboth a and b are OK')


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    unittest.main()
```